# FMOD::System *system; What does it do?

Tags: c++, fmod

Gotta learn FMOD For school project.

In the code (copied from the documentation):

```
FMOD_RESULT result;
FMOD::System *system;
result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);      // Create the main system object.
if (result != FMOD_OK)
{
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
    exit(-1);
}
result = system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);    // Initialize FMOD.
if (result != FMOD_OK)
{
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
    exit(-1);
}
```

What does the second line do (FMOD::System *system;)?
What does the next line do (result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);)?

I think the line FMOD::System *system; creates a pointer and the other line creates the system and checks for errors. I just don't get the need for pointers.

Could someone please explain 
Thank-you

Comment: You should have documentation included with the SDK.

Comment: @Nabla, Lots of C libraries will work well with `SomeStruct s; Create(&s);` No need for a pointer in your code there. Evidently, this function takes a double pointer, though, and I'm guessing it's an abstract class or something because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You first declare a pointer of type `FMOD::System*` and then the function `FMOD::System_Create` will populate the pointer with the *system object*. So, if nothing failed, after the third line `system` will point to a valid object of type `FMOD::System` so that you can call `system->init` few lines below.

Unfortunately the documentation for `FMOD` is not publicly available so I cannot tell much more. But if you have been given access to it, you should find all the informations you need in there.